# Can someone please explain the following javascript code snippets? (NOOB)

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code is part of a program which returns the largest number within an array. Could someone please explain the following? Thanks

```
  if (parseInt(nums[0]) < parseInt(nums[1])) { nums.splice(0,1); }
        else { nums.splice(1,1); }
```

Comment: It's removing the smaller value... except it would fail if you tried this on the array `[4.999, 4]` since the values are interpreted as integers. So it's not very good code. It also modifies the array in order to get an aggregate value which is also not good practice.

Answer (score 3):

The basic is understanding what [`.splice` does<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

So it will **modify** your array by removing an item depending on the passed params

> **array**.**splice**(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])

```js
var nums = ["2", 4];

if (parseInt(nums[0]) < parseInt(nums[1])) {
   nums.splice(0,1);    // At index 0 remove 1 item
} else { 
   nums.splice(1,1);    // At index 1 remove 1 item
}

console.log( nums )     // Modified array
```

PS:

- as you noticed, the code works only for Arrays of length 2; it only compares the 0 and 1 index: `nums[0]` `nums[1]`
- If your array is `[1, 1]` (same values) - nothing will happen.
- If your array is `[1.9, 1]` - `[1]` will be returned, since you're using `parseInt`
- It's good habit to use *radix* with `parseInt(value, radix)` like `parseInt(nums[0], 10)`

Comment: @gman no. In the case of the snippet in the question, the description of the side-effect is accurate and comprehensive. There's no need to explain things the function isn't doing here, when there's perfectly good documentation for it in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote NOOB I think it's important to be clear.

The [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method deletes 0 or more items from an array at a specified index and inserts 0 or more items at that index.

The signature is `someArray.splice(startNdx, deleteCount[, ...itemsToInsert])`

In the code you posted, this part

```
nums.splice(0,1);
```

starts at index 0 and deletes 1 element from the array. In other words if the array was `[5, 6, 7]` it would become `[6, 7]`

```
nums.splice(1,1);
```

This part starts at index 1 and deletes 1 element from the array. In other words if the array was `[5, 6, 7]` it would become `[5, 7]`.

The [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) parts convert strings to integers which suggests the array contains strings not numbers (or might optionally contain strings). Assuming the array does contain strings then without the `parseInt` part it would be comparing strings not numbers which is a different type of compare. Since you didn't show the contents of the array it's hard to know exactly what it's trying to do but for example

```
"00" < "0000"
```

is true where as

```
parseInt("00") < parseInt("0000")
```

is not true. Similarly

```
"000_bob" < "000_jill" is true
```

but

```
parseInt("000_bob") < parseInt("000_jill")
```

is not true

So the code is checking if the first value is less than the second but it's comparing by integer instead of string.

Someone else claimed this was bad code but it's not bad code without knowing the context it which it is being used.